# Formatting output of callback function

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have the following callback function.

```
// This is the callback function to display the select data in the table
static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **szColName)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
      std::cout << " = " << argv[i] << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "\n";

  return 0;
}

// prepare our sql statements
const char *pSQL[6];
pSQL[0] = "SELECT * FROM User";

// execute sql
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, pSQL[i], callback, 0, &szErrMsg);
    if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "SQL Error: " << szErrMsg << std::endl;
        sqlite3_free(szErrMsg);
        break;
    }
}
```

which produces the following output

```
1
mark
mark@email.com
98989898
mark
mark
ADMN
U
Where are you studying
SIM
0

2
ken
ken@email.com
92222898
ken
ken
ADMN
U
Where are you studying
SIM
0

3
joseph
joseph@email.com
92333718
joseph
joseph
ADMN
U
Where are you studying
SIM
0

4
ricky
ricky@email.com
81822801
ricky
ricky
ADMN
U
Where are you studying
SIM
0

5
ck
ck@email.com
94567828
ck
ck
ADMN
U
Where are you studying
SIM
0
```

I need it to be formatted horizontally like this instead of vertically:

```
1    mark      mark@email.com      98989898    mark      mark      ADMN    U    Where are you studying    SIM    0
2    ken       ken@email.com       92222898    ken       ken       ADMN    U    Where are you studying    SIM    0
3    joseph    joseph@email.com    92333718    joseph    joseph    ADMN    U    Where are you studying    SIM    0
4    ricky     ricky@email.com     81822801    ricky     ricky     ADMN    U    Where are you studying    SIM    0
5    ck        ck@email.com        94567828    ck        ck        ADMN    U    Where are you studying    SIM    0
```

I tried using this in the callback function:

```
1) std::cout << argv[i] << "\t";
2) std::cout << argv[i] << setw(15);
3) std::cout << setw(15) << argv[i];
```

But all it gave me is badly formatted rows.

```
1   mark    test@email.com  98989898    mark    mark    ADMN    U   Where are you studying  SIM 0   
2   ken ken@email.com   92222898    ken ken ADMN    U   Where are you studying  SIM 0   
3   joseph  joseph@email.com    92333718    joseph  joseph  ADMN    U   Where are you studying  SIM 0   
4   ricky   ricky@email.com 81822801    ricky   ricky   ADMN    U   Where are you studying  SIM 0   
5   ck  ck@email.com    94567828    ck  ck  ADMN    U   Where are you studying  SIM 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and possible [`std::left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) manipulators.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `std::endl` inside the `for` loop.  This manipulator is causing each item in the `for` loop to be printed on a new line.

Comment: Yeah, I did remove std::endl and tried one of the latter three:
1) std::cout << argv[i] << "\t";
2) std::cout << argv[i] << setw(15);
3) std::cout << setw(15) << argv[i];